# DMARC reports: why Google submitting the reports?

Tags: email, spf, dkim, dmarc

I configured DMARC in an email gateway solution and received the DMARC reports. My question is: why Google submitting the reports?

Comment: How is this related to programming? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregate reports show you how your domains are being used or abused without your knowledge or participation. If you do not want to receive the reports, you can omit the `rua` field in your DMARC record(s).

Comment: So the list I get is from domains and IPs that are using my domain improperly? Thank you!

Comment: The list you get is (typically) IP addresses, times, and DKIM/SPF validation results associated with domains that you've published records for. The IP addresses being misconfigured servers or (more often) malicious players who are using your domain name in their spam's sender addresses.

Comment: Thank you. Now it's clear to me. Is there any specific reason for Google to submit this report?

Comment: The purpose of DMARC should speak to this: "The goal of DMARC is to build on this system of senders and receivers collaborating to improve mail authentication practices of senders and enable receivers to reject unauthenticated messages." As a high-volume email provider, Gmail has an interest in people doing better email authentication and lowering the global spam rate.

Comment: No worries hope it helped!